# javascript library to list files from local folder

Tags: javascript, firefox, xul

does any one tell me, is there any possibility of loading files from a local folder in xul firefox using JS. Or how to create a dynamic menulist in Xul Firefox.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I believe that's two questions - maybe try posing them separately :)

Comment: There's an autocomplete component for that, but unfortunately it only works on Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=xul%20file%20system%20access) -> http://xulbase.com/node/5 -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/File_I%2F%2FO

Comment: I couldn't load the RDF tutorial.